# WordPress Sub domain

Tags: permalinks, htaccess, subdomains

I installed WordPress on sub domain and I have Permalinks as domain/subdomain.com. 
In this way this website is working correctly and the main website is accessible via subdomain.domain.com as well but using this URL its sub pages are causing Internal Server Error.
Is there any way to serve this website using both these type of URLs ?

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. If your permalinks go domain/subdomain.com/page-name that is broken AF and not going to load anything.

Answer (score 0):

did you try going to settings -> permalinks and clicking save?